How do I connect my 4" corrugated drain pipe to my 4" tee?
I'm doing a retaining wall in my yard, and I am installing one of these Wall Drain Pro things. The manufacturer told me on the phone it just needs to connect to a 4" tee. (And indeed in the detail schematics it says the external diameter is 3 7/8".)
At a local hardware store I picked up a length of 4" corrugated drain pipe, but they didn't have a Tee connector, so the next time I was at Home Depot I picked up one of these 4" tees.
It is stamped on the plastic as a 4" connector. The mouth sizes are all about 4.5 - 5 inches, however, and both the Wall Drain pro thing and the corrugated drain I purchased don't [feel like] they're making an actual seal on it.
I see the tee has little nibs in the outer thing that look like they're supposed to maybe grab onto the corrugations, but they're far too wide to do that. The pipes could actually be slid all the way through the tee if I push it.
It doesn't feel like it'll slip out -- due to friction from the tighter part of the tee -- and these things are all supposed to be holey to allow for waterflow anyway... But is this the way it's supposed to fit?
I was expecting it to be much tighter. But it feels like my 4" tee -- again despite being stickered as 4" and the plastic stamped as 4" -- is too large.
Anyone know with any definition? Thanks in advance.

The hardware store pipe may be unusually undersized.  Take it back and get the drain pipe from the same place you got the "T".  While there check that the drain pipe and T fit properly.  They should have a snug fit.

Thanks! The only problem is that the hardware store pipe is the exact same size as the Wall Drain Pro pipe. And I see on the Home Depot site they have an actual image with dimensions stating the side openings are 5.1" and 5.5" for the middle for some reason?!

Wrap all the joints in geotextile and be on your way.  That said, this Wall Drain Pro thing looks like a solution in search of a problem.  You should be wrapping your stone behind your wall with geotextile anyway, and if you wrap the front side too, water will pass from the soil into the stone, and through the stone to daylight, without needing an underdrain pipe and these wall drain outlets.
